# Closeness of two estimators of median under non parametric setup in a large sample situation

Tags: nonparametric, estimators, kernel-smoothing, quantile-regression, nadaraya-watson

**Median Regression under non-parametric set-up (Nadaraya Watson Estimate)**
Data: $\{(Y_i,X_i):1\le i\le n\}$
Interested in estimating $\phi(x)=\text{median}(Y|X=x).$

Possible estimates are

1. Minimize the following to get the weighted median i.e.,$$\min_{\phi}\sum_{i=1}^n|Y_i-\phi(x)|W_n(X_i;x,h_n)\quad\text{where, } W_n(X_i;x,h_n)=\frac{K(\frac{X_i-x}{h_n})}{\sum_{i=1}^nK(\frac{X_i-x}{h_n})}$$
   where, $K$ is a kernel function of choice.
2. Transform the data to $\{(Z^{(t)}_i,X_i)\}_i$ where, $Z_i^{(t)}=\mathbb{I}_{[Y_i\le t]}$. Find lowest value of $t$ for which the Nadaraya Watson estimate of the conditional mean of $Z^{(t)}$ given $X=x$ is $0.5$ (or crosses $0.5$). $t$ is the estimator for the conditional median of $Y|X=x$.

Under large sample conditions, these two estimates are close. How do I show this in the case of Uniform Kernel?

Comment: How is this different from your [earlier question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/596124/247274)?

Comment: @Dave the other question is specifically asking about the implementation of the first estimator mentioned here: how to find it. Here, I just want a rough proof/verification in a particular case to show that the two estimators are not far off.

Comment: @Dave I figured out the implementation of the first estimator (the previous question), so deleting it.

Comment: Please post a self-answer rather than delete the question. That way, others can learn from what you did, and if you’ve made a mistake (maybe you didn’t, but maybe you did), the community can vet your work.

Comment: @Dave ah, understood. Will keep it in mind next time. This one, however, I stil lhaven't figured how to verify.